# getting EXITED error:pointer to an array in c

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
 unsigned char a[3];
 unsigned char (*p)[3]=NULL;
 unsigned char *q=NULL;
 int i = 0;
 a[0]=0;
 a[1]=1;
 a[2]=2;
 p=&a;
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   if((*p)[3] == a[3]){
     printf("*p[%d]:%d a[%d]:%d",i,(*p)[3],i,a[3]);
   }
 }
}

o/p:
*p[0]:0 a[0]:0*p[1]:0 a[1]:0*p[2]:0 a[2]:0
Exited: ExitFailure 14
```

I want to copy an array of size 3 to a pointer and to do a comparision. I have written a sample program. But i'm getting an error value.
I ran this using an online c compiler . (codepad.org)
Please help me in identifying my mistakes.

Comment: You seem to forget that that arrays start their indexing at zero, and the highest index is the size minus one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `p` is an array, not a pointer. You can't re-assign an array to point somewhere else, so the line

```
p = &a;
```

is not valid.

Also, C indexes from 0 as you seem to know, so comparisons using index `[3]` for arrays of size 3 are not valid.

Further, in your comparison loop you're not actually using `i` to index, but instead always comparing using the invalid constant index `[3]`.

It's not very clear from your code (`q` is not used, for instance), but it *sounds* as if you want to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char a[3];
unsigned char *p;

p = malloc(sizeof a);
if(p != NULL) /* If allocation succeeded, p is valid. */
{
  int i;

  memcpy(p, a, sizeof a);
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof a; ++i)
  {
    if(p[i] == a[i])
      printf("p[%d]:%d a[%d]:%d\n", i, p[i], i, a[i]);
  }
  free(p);
}
```

Of course, this will always print all the numbers, since `memcpy()` will never fail to copy the memory. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here You have declared the **return type** of main function as **int**, but you are not returning anything from it.
So **return** any **integer** value (like 1) or make the main function's return type **void**.